How can I find if another DAG is currently running and what configs were passed to it
I'm using airflow 1.10.12
I have DAG A and DAG B. DAG A runs every 12 hours and DAG B is only triggered manually with a configuration JSON.
I know how to access the configuration JSON in DAG B, but is there a way to tell from DAG A if DAG B is running and it's configuration JSON?

You may try DagRun to check DAG B status inside DAG A
An example may look like

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.models import DagRun


def check_dag_b_status(**kwargs):
    dag_b_runs = DagRun.find(dag_id='dag_b', state='running')

    if dag_b_runs:
        # fetch configure from DAG B
        dag_b_config = Variable.get("dag_b_config", default_var=None)
        print("configure:", dag_b_config)
    else:
        # do other work

dag_a_task = PythonOperator(
    task_id='check_dag_b',
    python_callable=check_dag_b_status,
    provide_context=True,
    dag=dag_a
)

